# How tomcat gets user role information?

Tags: java, tomcat

I would like to know internals of tomcat. I configured my web application in 'BASIC' authentication mode. When I logged in for first time, browser asks for credentials. Till this it is fine, may be at the time of login, tomcat reading 'tomcat-users.xml' and set the role. But I am wondering, how tomcat knows the role of the user in subsequent requests. How it keep tracking of the role? Internally is it maintaining some data structure (or) is it keeping this information in session?

Comment: after login, the informations of users are taken alive in app session

Comment: Cookies, URL rewriting, or session data are the alternatives.

Comment: Well, @Hari Krishna, I suppose they are all one ... :)